# Why interface and abstract class could have default access modfier and not protected

Tags: java

I'm preparing for java OCA exam, and while running some test, I remarked that an interface/abstract class could be declared with package private access modifier, but not protected even if default access modifier is "strict" than protected.
.
here is an example 
**Example 1**

```
//package 1;
public abstract class T1{..}
// package 2;
public class T2 extends T1{..}
```

**Example 2**

```
//package 1;
abstract class T1{..}
// package 2;
// compiler error 
public class T2 extends T1{..}
```

**Example 3**

```
//package 1;
protected abstract class T1{..} //doesn't work
```

can anyone explain ?

Comment: An abstract class can certainly have `protected` members.

Comment: And a nested interface or abstract class can itself have `protected` access.  But a top-level class or interface cannot be `protected` because that wouldn't make any sense.  What do you think `protected` would mean in such a case?

Comment: The examples you added, particularly the second, do not correspond to the text or title of your question.

Comment: you are right, I updated the question, thank you